# How to create a self-contained executable for a .NET Core Console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dll, executable

I want to create a self-contained executable for my .NET Core Console application that can be run on the command line without the `dotnet` command. When I try to create a self contained executable using `dotnet publish -r osx-x64`, a `.dll` with the project name is created in the output folder, e.g. `myproject.dll`, instead of an EXE file (I'm assuming on MacOS self contained applications are EXE files just like on Windows). I cannot run `myproject.dll` directly without using the `dotnet` command, I have to run `dotnet myproject.dll arg1` in order for the program to execute.

Comment: It's creating publsh folder with self-contained  executable ... self-contained  doesn't want a "single file" ... if you mean single file than you can use `/p:PublishSingleFile=true` switch

Comment: @Sinatr thanks, but the answers in that question are bit too Windows specific. I now know what I was doing wrong, and can execute the self-contained executable.

Comment: @Selvin self-contained does not mean a single file, really? Then what does self contained refer to here? That switch is not clear, can you give the full command? **Update**: I now see that self-contained refers to the application (i.e. the project) not a single file.

Comment: as it's written in the docs ... it will works without runtime installed ...about switch ... add it at the end of your command (remeber executable on linux and osx doesn't have extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable file is in the publish folder. In Windows executables have a .exe file extension where as on Linux and OSX (i.e. MacOS) executables do not have file extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to @MyWrathAcademia's answer...

A self contained application does not require the .NET Runtime on the target system, and bundles it's own .NET Runtime. A runtime dependent application depends on the .NET Runtime on the target system, so it has to be executed using "dotnet run".

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-application) for more information.